# Reporting in VS lightswitch

Tags: reporting, visual-studio-lightswitch

What are the reporting capabilities of LightSwitch? Will 3rd party controls be needed or will Microsoft offer integration with Reporting Services?

---

Taken from Michael's [blog](http://lightswitchhelpwebsite.com/Blog/tabid/61/EntryId/32/First-Look-At-The-DevExpress-LightSwitch-Reporting-Control.aspx)

DevExpress released a free reporting control for LightSwitch. And this is excelent news.

Comment: Also see:
[Printing Sql Server Reports (.rdlc) With LightSwitch](http://lightswitchhelpwebsite.com/Blog/tabid/61/EntryId/11/Printing-Sql-Server-Reports-rdlc-With-LightSwitch.aspx) and [Printing With LightSwitch](http://lightswitchhelpwebsite.com/Blog/tabid/61/EntryId/3/Printing-With-LightSwitch.aspx)

Comment: In addition to Michael's suggestion: Derek @ Spursoft Solutions has an SSRS Control here:<br/> http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/SpursoftLSControls There is also an interesting article that I would recommend reading here: http://tejana.wordpress.com/2011/04/29/microsoft-lightswitch-printing-html/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

DevExpress has a pure LightSwitch reporting tool. It includes:

- Native Entity and Query Binding
- Native LS Report Screen
- Asynchronous Data Fetch (makes it more responsive)

Here is some information:

- [DevExpress LightSwitch Page](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/LightSwitch/)
- [Getting Started Video](http://tv.devexpress.com/#XtraReportsGettingStartedLightSwitch)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Apparently DevExpress no longer offer the XtraReports for Lightswitch product.

I received this information from www.componentsource.com when I looked into purchasing it (they spoke to the publisher because I had a query regarding whether I would also need to purchase a DXperience subscription).

The DevExpress website somewhat confusingly still has webpage http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/LightSwitch/ for purchasing XtraReports for Lightswitch (as of 14 June 2012).

Comment: componentsource.com have had further communication with the publisher who have now said _"Because LightSwitch is incompatible with Silverlight 5, both XtraReports for LightSwitch and DXEditors for LightSwitch are only available as part of DXperience v2011 vol 1. So I can create a special order for the customer, but he will have to use the previous version."_         So looks like it is still available but that you need to ensure you get the correct version.

Answer (score 1):

If you decide to settle for a 3rd party reporting, check out [Telerik Reporting](http://tlrk.it/keOuIm) - there is a [blog on how to use its Silverlight report viewer in LightSwtich](http://tlrk.it/ke2yHc).

There are a few considerations, which could be considered drawbacks depending on your case:

- Local binding is not possible currently, since the reports are generated server-side and only previewed on the Silverlight client.
- Telerik Reporting does not offer an end-user report designer yet, so it is still a pure developer solution.

I hope this helps...